# jquery cookie - per site rather than per page

Tags: jquery, cookies, jquery-cookie

We built a notification with fancybox that needs to be shown to all of our users once but currently it's showing once on every page of the site and setting a cookie for every page the visitor visits, our code is as follows:

```
// jQuery Cookie popup
$(function() {
    if ($.cookie('cd-notification-cookie')) {
        // it hasn't been three days yet
    } else {
        $.fancybox.open([
            {
                href : '#notification'
            } 
        ], {
            maxWidth    : 420,
            maxHeight   : 800,
            fitToView   : false,
            width       : '90%',
            height      : 'auto',
            autoSize    : false,
            closeClick  : false,
            closeEffect : 'none'   
        });
      // set cookie to expire in 3 days
      $.cookie('cd-notification-cookie', 'true', { expires: 3});
    }
});
```

Is it possible to set a global cookie for the whole website instead of a per page basis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to set the path to the base of the application like

```
$.cookie('cd-notification-cookie', 'true', { expires: 3, path: '/'});
```